# How to autofill code with initials or shortcut line of code in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, random, visual-studio-2019, shortcut

For example i want to write `(rand%(MaxValue-MinValue+1))-MinValue` i don't want to write this line everytime i want to use it but is there a way to make Visual Studio auto write it when i just need to write `rand` or `R`.

Comment: Hi, have you got any updates?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `#define`?

Here is an example:

```
#define rand(r,max,min) ((r%(max-min+1))-min)
```

And to call it:

```
rand(_rand, MaxValue, MinValue);
```

Comment: thank you. I think that is of a way too, but isn't there a shorter one.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use snippet, it's very convenient.

You need to create a new txt file on the desktop, and then enter the following code in the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>propertyName</Title>
      <Shortcut>rand</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
  <Code Language="cpp">
    <![CDATA[
    (rand%(MaxValue-MinValue+1))-MinValue
    ]]>
  </Code>
  <Declarations>   
  </Declarations>
</Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Then change the suffix of the txt file to snippet, and finally import the snippet according to the method in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets?view=vs-2022).

**RESULT:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks Yao. It's quite a long way but it maybe better for future uses

Comment: @Tri_Hai05 , Hi, this is a good way to achieve your needs, and you can also customize other shortcuts by modifying <Shortcut>rand</Shortcut> and (rand%(MaxValue-MinValue+1))-MinValue.